# Regex to match exact string

Tags: regex

I am having some trouble to figure out a way to detect a prefix on a message by having the exact amount of characters, for example:
I tried the regex `^[!]{1}` the messages I was testing with were:

```
   !test
   !!!test
```

But that regex would mark both strings as starting with the prefix.
I have saved both prefixes and I want to detect which one is being parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the regex what an invalid match is as well. One way to do this is to look for an exclamation mark and then anything but an exclamation mark.

```
^![^!]
```

or you could look for an `!` then an alpha character:

```
^![a-zA-Z]
```

depends what should follow.

Comment: Ooh okay, got it! So in this case it'll match `!t` instead of just `!` however that's totally fine I can just remove one character from it since I know it'll always get the first character from the message

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `remove one character from it`. The regex said a valid match was "if string starts with an exclamation mark", we've update to say "if string start with an exclamation mark and isn't followed by an exclamation mark", or "if string starts with an exclamation mark and isn't followed by an alpha character".